# How to create LiveSD image of raspberian?

Tags: linux, software-installation, windows

I set up all settings I wanted for one Raspbery PI 3B using Raspberian OS. How to make a liveSD like image of my SD card (on Windows)? in other words I want to turn my sd card contents into something I could install onto other SD cards, plug them into other RPis and get all I instaled once up and running (e.g. B.A.T.M.A.N network)?

Answer (score 2):

Just use win32diskimager to "read" instead of write. This creates a .img file of your configured OS which you can copy to other SD cards.

Comment: You should however make a few changes to each new install 1) generate a new set of SSH keys, 2) if using static IP's you will need to change the address to prevent collisions. A better option may be to use the basic image and then script or use a config management tool like puppet or ansible. This lets you treat your infrastructure as code (store it in version control, test it etc.) and can handle all of the specific changes (keys, IP addresses etc.)